# MPMusicPlayerController live streaming

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am developing an application that plays a live HTTP web radio streaming (.pls, .mp3 ...). Can i use the MPMusicPlayerController to play the stream ? Thaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can play streaming audio using `MPMusicPlayerController`. You should look at `AVPlayer`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];    
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];    
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];    
AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];    
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have just investigated about this and i found that i should use AVPlayer. Thanks.

Comment: than how soundcloud play it on systemPlayer ?

Comment: MPMusicPlayerController are designed specifically for the media playback. For example you can play a song which is in cloud using this class. You will get an item in the form of "MPMediaItem"...